# How do I get current typing text in TextEditor and give auto complete like mention or hashtag in draftjs

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

How do I get current typing text in Text Editor and give auto complete like mention or hashtag in draftjs

here is simple
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-newton-hn18i

I tried autocomplete it enable on separate input field not in the Editor,

So is their a better way to achieve auto complete (give dropdown ) in draftjs

Answer (score 1):

you can find what you are asking for with Decorators concept in draft.js

which consist of fo two core things a strategy function where  you put your logic 
and a custom component 
http://davidandsuzi.com/how-to-use-draft-decorators/